# Process input as a stream of bits

Tags: java, input, bit

I am dealing with a situation where in the input that I have to read is a stream of bits. So the input can be of the following form. The first line tells the number of bits that I would be receiving and then the next line is a stream of bits all in one go.

```
10
011011110
```

Now what I am trying is if its possible to handle the input that I am receiving as a bit. I know that the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html class has a method nextByte() that processes the next token of the input as a byte. I was wondering if its possible to process input as an array of bits.

Comment: So the input is actually a stream of characters, with possible values '0', '1', and '\n'?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov yes it is a stream of characters but it is to be interpreted as bits

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 you have a class `BitSet` which can be used this way:

```
public static BitSet fromByte(byte b)  
{  
    BitSet bits = new BitSet(8);  
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
    {  
       bits.set(i, (b & 1) == 1);  
       b >>= 1;  
     }  
     return bits;  
 }
```

You would have to get `byte` from the stream and then simply call on it `fromByte` method.